# How to properly handle race condition caused by retry worker

Tags: event-handling, microservices, race-condition, event-driven, retry-logic

In one of the services we had some connection issues and we are getting random timeouts (we think it is because of the client library. it is one of the caching services). We decided to handle it by putting it in the queue and retrying on a separate worker until we solve the underlying issue.

However, there is a case. let's say we want to put the value "A" to cache. but it fails. so we put it in the queue to retry again. but during this time user fire a delete request to remove that data and we call it without any timeouts (no error, but no record to delete as well). then our retry strategy writes that data to cache (which is supposed to be deleted and not be there).

How would we handle this scenario? I first thought maybe we can raise an error if delete doesn't delete anything but then I see it also has so many complications and can end with an endless retry even

Answer (score 0):

It appear as the issue is coming as you are doing actual action on main thread and if it fails then only doing retry through queue by worker thread.

If you do actual action as well through worker thread as well through queue then issue will be resolved.

Or 2nd solution is, you can track all the keys that are in queue for retry. If there is any action related to key already in queue then queue the actual action as well. Like delete should be queue as the action for A as retry action on A is already queue.

2nd solution is little inefficient.